# How to define and use global, filenames in a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, script

EDIT: Changed the requirement for dynamically-calculated variable names as I don't strictly need this for my use case, and a solution was provided that works for me.

This is probably impossible to do, but here goes:

I have a bash script that does some formatting and filetype conversions on an input file that is ASCII xyz (latitude, longitude, depth) triples, and creates various output files types. I am trying to avoid having to wrangle output filenames each and every time I write a script similar to this; I guess I am trying to find a way to calculate output file names *globally* on my system given any input filename, either by '`export`'ing the output filename suffixes in bashrc, or in some other file that gets sourced in my scripts.

So for example, in a typical script I would build output filenames dynamically from the input file given on the command line:

```
INPUT=$1

INPUT_SUFFIX=`echo $INPUT | cut -d. -f2`
INPUT_BASE=$(basename $INPUT .$INPUT_SUFFIX)
OUTPUT_TEXT="${INPUT_BASE}txt"
OUTPUT_TIFF="${INPUT_BASE}tif"
OUTPUT_GRID="${INPUT_BASE}grd"

#...etc, plus other output formats
```

I am trying to find a way to avoid having to do these tedious output filename definitions in every script. I know I could simply copy and paste the code every time, but it would be more efficient to define how the output filenames are to be constructed once, and globally across my system.

So in *any* script I write, for any value of `$1`, a variable like `$OUTPUT_TIFF` would *already* be dynamically calculated from the input, and would evaluate to "${1}.tif".

Comment: I've edited the question, dropping the requirement for dynamically-calculated variables as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) is to write the common code to a regular file and source the file every time you need it. In Bash [you can even pass arguments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5027/108618). This is "on demand", not "dynamically calculated" though; i.e. if `$1` changes for whatever reason then you will need to source again to update your variables.